# Haskell - Match Type Instance

Tags: haskell, types, filtering, instance, data-partitioning

I have defined a Haskell type similar to the following:

```
data TypeData = TypeA Int | TypeB String | TypeC Char deriving (Eq, Show)
```

At some point, I need a way to filter a `[TypeData]` for all non-TypeC instances.  The signature of the function I am trying to write is:

```
-- Returns a tuple containing (TypeC elements, non-TypeC elements)
partitionTypeCs :: [TypeData] -> ([TypeData],[TypeData])
```

The `partition` function seemed suitable for this:

```
-- Attempt:
partitionTypeCs data = partition (TypeData -> Bool) data
```

However, I cannot figure out what function would match the type signature `TypeData -> Bool`.  It looks like I need a function that can determine if a type instance is of a specific instance.  I know I can use pattern matching for that by writing another function (`isTypeC (TypeC _) = True`), but is there a more generic way or an lineline way of matching type instances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
partitionTypeCs = partition f where
  f (TypeC _) = False
  f _ = True
```

I must admit that I don't understand why you don't like this.  You can't compare against a constructor using equality because there is an unknown parameter involved.  Pattern matching does exactly what must be done here.

Answer (score 3):

Pattern matching is pretty much the answer here.  It'd take you 3 additional lines (including type signature), so it's not like it's a long solution.  You could probably write some template haskell that could do it in general, but that seems like too complicated a solution for something so simple.

```hs
isTypeC :: TypeData -> Bool
isTypeC (TypeC _) = True
isTypeC _ = False
```